# Writing Cucumber tests that pass extra information

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cucumber, capybara

I have a Ruby on Rails program with feature tests in Cucumber.

I just implemented a feature where an admin can create a new password for a client-user. Now, on the "edit client" page, there's an additional button that allows the admin to set the password. Now, I just need to make a cucumber test.

I am trying to base this off of the normal test for client changing password, and the test for admin changing the user's information. What I have is this:

```
Feature: Analyst changes client's password
  As an Analyst
  I want to change client's password
  So that I can reset the client's account

  Background:
    Given the following client accounts
      | email             | password |
      | user1@someorg.com | password |
    And I am logged in as an admin

  @javascript
  Scenario: Update a Client user
    Given I navigate to the Clients Management Page
    When I edit the Client User "user1@someorg.com"
    And I click on "button"
    Then I should be on the Clients Password Page

  @javascript
  Scenario: Can change password if confirmation matches
    Given I navigate to the Clients Password Page
    And I enter "Password1" as the password
    And I enter "Password1" as the password confirmation
    And I submit the form
    Then I should be taken to the Client Landing Page
    And The client's password should be "Password1"
```

In the steps, I have:

```
Given /^I navigate to the Clients Password Page$/ do
  client_management_index_page = ClientsPasswordPage.new Capybara.current_session
  client_management_index_page.visit
end

Then /^I should be on the Clients Password Page$/ do
  client_password_page = ClientsPasswordPage.new Capybara.current_session
  expect(client_password_page).to be_current_page
end
```

and ClientsPaswordPage:

```
class ClientsPasswordPage
  include PageMixin
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

  def initialize session
    initialize_page session, edit_admin_client_password_path
  end
end
```

except that edit_admin_client_password_path takes an :id, for the user who's being edited. I can't figure out how to get that information into it.

In case it matters, I'm using Devise for the security stuff...

Comment: As an aside, since there isn't anywhere in stackExchange land to ask, if anyone has a good Cucumber tutorial in RoR, that would be useful as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this. The simplest is to realize that you're only creating one client during the test so

```
Client.first # whatever class represents clients
```

will always be that client. Obviously that doesn't work if you have tests where you create one more than client, so then you can create instance variables in your cucumber steps which get set on the World and can then be accessed from other steps and passed to your page objects

```
When I edit the Client User "user1@someorg.com"
  @current_client = Client.find_by(email: "user1@someorg.com") # obviously would actually be a parameter to the step
  ...
end

Then /^I should be on the Clients Password Page$/ do
  client_password_page = ClientsPasswordPage.new Capybara.current_session, @current_client
  expect(client_password_page).to be_current_page
end
```

of course without the page object overhead this would just become

```
Then /^I should be on the Clients Password Page$/ do
  expect(page).to have_current_path(edit_admin_client_password_path(@current_client))
end
```

Comment: How does "I should be on the clients password page" know what @current_client is?

Comment: @BrianPostow Because you set it in "When I edit the Client User..." - Instance variables get created in the cucumber World and are available to all later steps in that scenario- https://docs.cucumber.io/cucumber/state/#world-object

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of things you can do to simplify this scenario. If you have simpler scenarios, with simpler step definitions then it will be easier to solve implementation problems like how you get a client in one step to be available in a second step.

The main way to simplify scenarios is to not have anything at all in the scenario that explains HOW you have implemented the functionality. If you take all the clicking on buttons, filling in fields, and visiting pages out of your scenarios you can focus on the business problem.

So how about

```
Background
  Given there is a client
  And I am logged in as an admin

Scenario: Change clients password
  When I change the clients password
  Then the client should have a new password
```

**Note:** This immediately raises the question 'How does the client find out about there new password?', which is what good simple scenarios do, they make you ask valuable questions. Answering this is probably out of scope here.

Now lets have a look at the implementation.

```
Given 'there is a client' do
  @client = create_new_client
end

When 'I change the clients password' do
  visit admin_change_password_path(@client)
  change_client_password(client: @client)
end
```

Just this might be sufficient to get you on the right path. In addition something like

```
Given 'I am logged in as an admin' do
  @i = create_admin_user
  login_as(user: @i)
end
```

would help.

What we have done here is

1. Push the HOW down your stack so that now the code you right to make this work is out of your scenarios and step definitions
2. Used variable to communicate between steps the line `@client = create_new_client` creates a global (actually global to Cucumber::World) variable that is available in all step definitions

You can create helper methods by adding modules to Cucumber world and defining methods in them. Note these methods are global so you have to think carefully about names (there are very good reasons why these methods are global). So

```
module UserStepHelper
  def create_new_client
    ...
  end

  def create_admin_user
    ...
  end

  def change_client_password(client: )
    ...
  end
end
World UserStepHelper
```

Will create a helper method you can use in any of your step definitions.

You can see an example of this approach [here](https://github.com/diabolo/cuke_up). A project I used for a talk at CukeUp 2013. Perhaps you could use this as your tutorial example.